# Referencing AngularJS Scopes with other Services

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope, geolocation

I'm working on an AngularJS Project and I'm having some trouble with my services. I created one services that returns two functions. One returns the current location on the user and the other returns an API URL. The problem I'm facing is that the API URL requires a Latitude and Longitude. I want to grab that **current locations data** and pass it into the **URL** and data bind it to my view. How do I go about referencing scopes from each services to one another?
Heres my Code:

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])

.controller('HomeCtrl', ['$scope', '$q', '$http', 'myService',
  function($scope, $q, $http, myService) {

    myService.getLocation().then(function(data) {
      $scope.lat = data.coords.latitude;
      $scope.long = data.coords.longitude;
      console.log($scope.lat, $scope.long);
    });
    myService.getAirports().then(function(data) {

    });
  }
])

//MYSERVICE FACTORY
.factory('myService', function($http, $q, $cordovaGeolocation) {
  return {
    getLocation: function() {
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      $cordovaGeolocation.getCurrentPosition().then(function(position) {
        var lat = position.coords.latitude;
        console.log(lat);
        deferred.resolve(position)
      });
      return deferred.promise;
    },


    getAirports: function() {
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      var url = 'https://api.flightstats.com/flex/airports/rest/v1/jsonp/withinRadius/' + PLACE LONGITUDE HERE + '/' + PLACE LONGITUDE HERE + '/10?appId=02a5e867&appKey=1f2075112529890985b1dd8ea0f0a419' + '&callback=JSON_CALLBACK';
      var config = {
        method: 'GET',
        callback: 'JSON_CALLBACK'
      }
      $http.jsonp(url, config)
        .then(function(data) {
          var lat = data.data.airports[0].latitude;
          deferred.resolve(data)
        });
      return deferred.promise;
    }
  }
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mwr1vvv3/)

and if there is anything I can do to simplify my code, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to just place your call to the second service inside the then method of the first service and pass in the lat/lng data:

```
myService.getLocation().then(function(data){
    $scope.lat = data.coords.latitude;
    $scope.long = data.coords.longitude;
    console.log($scope.lat, $scope.long);
    myService.getAirports($scope.lat, $scope.long).then(function(data){

    });
});
```

Then you can just use the data in the getAirports method:

```
getAirports: function(lat, lng) {
 ....
 var url = 'https://api.flightstats.com/flex/airports/rest/v1/jsonp/withinRadius/'+ lat+'/'+lng+'/10?appId=02a5e867&appKey=1f2075112529890985b1dd8ea0f0a419' + '&callback=JSON_CALLBACK';
 ....
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Daniel . Worked instantly!!